# R: dplyr - Rename column name by position instead of name

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to know if there is a way to rename column names by position of the column, rather than changing by column name.

Below snippet shows how to change by name.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

gd_url  <- "http://tiny.cc/gapminder"
gtbl  <- gd_url %>%
  read.delim %>%
  tbl_df

gtbl  <- gtbl %>% rename(life_exp = lifeExp, 
                         gdp_percap = gdpPercap)
gtbl
```

Comment: So how would you like to do the renaming? It's not quite clear what the approach you are after is.

Comment: If you choose certain columns and change names, you could do something like `select(gtbl, life_exp = 5)`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to do `names(gtbl)[5:6] <- c('life_exp', 'gdp_percap')`

Comment: @akrun I would to that too.

Comment: `rename()` forces you to use names for a reason

Comment: Thanks... So the answer is,  it cannot be done (in dplyr way) and there is a good reason for it :)

Comment: Related questions: [How to dplyr rename a column, by column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42769650/1895415) and [Rename data frame columns, specified by column index, as a function of those indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75795602/1895415)

Answer (score 59):

Much simpler: you can rename a column just by using numbers. This works:

```
df <- df %>% 
        rename(newNameForFirstColumn = 1, newNameForSecondColumn = 2)
```

Answer (score 20):

If you prefer to stick within the dplyr pipe-world, as of dplyr 0.7.2 it is possible to rename by position using the following nomenclature:

Using your original example:

```
gtbl  <- gtbl %>% rename("life_exp" = !!names(.[5]),
                         "gdp_percap" = !!names(.[6]))
```

Regards for dredging up an older post.  I had a similar problem and viewed this question before figuring out this alternative solution.