# Using replace_na with across in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace NA in a subset of columns and I want to use tidyverse/dplyr syntax.
dplyr v1.0.2

In the following, I want only to replace the NAs with 999 in columns ab,ac but not in ads

```
tbf <- tibble( ab = c(1,3,NA), ac = c(23,NA,33), d = c(22,22,NA), ads = c('ds', NA, "dwe"))
tbf %>% mutate(across(starts_with('a') & where(is.numeric)), ~replace_na(999))
```

does not seem to work.

I tried `~replace_na(.x,999)` too. That didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `fn` (you are using `replace_na`) needs to be inside the `across`. You then also need to reference the current column by inserting a `.` in the `replace_na`. This way you can use the filtering  you are proposing in your question (columns starting with "a" and with numeric values) as opposed to the other answers here which specifically use column names.

```
tbf %>% mutate(across(starts_with('a') & where(is.numeric), ~replace_na(.,999)))
```

Answer (score 4):

**Data**

```
tbf <- tibble( ab = c(1,3,NA), ac = c(23,NA,33), d = c(22,22,NA), ads = c('ds', NA, "dwe"))
```

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tbf %>% 
  mutate(
    across(ab:ac, ~replace_na(.x, 999))
  )
```

**Output**

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      ab    ac     d ads  
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1    23    22 ds   
#> 2     3   999    22 NA 
#> 3   999    33    NA dwe
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What is the difference between `replace_na(.x, 999)` and `replace_na(., 999)`?  Both worked for me, but I don't understand the first one.

Comment: @Earlien https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488162/use-of-tilde-and-period-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works.

```
tbf %>% mutate(across(starts_with('a') & where(is.numeric), ~replace(., is.na(.), 999)))

> tbf %>% mutate(across(starts_with('a') & where(is.numeric), ~replace(., is.na(.), 999)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ab    ac     d ads  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    23    22 ds   
2     3   999    22 NA   
3   999    33    NA dwe  
>
```

Comment: Neither replace_na or replace within the across worked for me, though clearly it worked for you. This is surprising. Could you tell me what version you are using?

Comment: I am using  dplyr version 1.0.0, how about you?

Comment: It worked fine in a clean session. However, I accepted Juljo's answer  But this answer works too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#Code
tbf %>% mutate(across(ab:ac, ~ifelse(is.na(.),999,.)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ab    ac     d ads  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    23    22 ds   
2     3   999    22 NA   
3   999    33    NA dwe
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with `tidyr` as well.

```
tbf %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('a') & where(is.numeric))) %>% 
  replace_na(list(ab = 999, ac = 999))
```

```
    # A tibble: 3 x 4
         ab    ac     d ads  
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
    1     1    23    22 ds   
    2     3   999    22 NA   
    3   999    33    NA dwe
```

Comment: This is close, but I don't want to specify the column names explicitly in the replace_na. Is this possible?

Comment: This solution works. However what are you using the `mutate(...) ` call for here? Seems not to do anything