# Create new data columns by dividing two columns, determining divident/divisor in third column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe structured like the following, with the number of `x_L` and `x_R` pair being possibly up to 100.

```
ID  Side  A_L   A_R   B_L   B_R
1    0     7     5     6     3
2    1     3     2     3     1
3    0     6     3     4     5
```

I know want to create a new column `A_ratio` for each pair `A_L`and `A_R`. The value of that new column for each ID should either be `A_L / A_R` if `Side==0`, or `A_R / A_L` if `Side==1`.

My attempt was implementing a `for` loop with an increment of 2, to cover each pair only once, and using `ifelse` to differentiate between the two possible values of `Side`

```
for (i in seq(from = 3, to = length(df), by = 2)) {
  df[sub("_L", "_ratio",(names(df[i]))] <-ifelse(df[2]==0, df[i] / df[i+1], df[i+1] / df[i])
}
```

This however leads to the following warning:

```
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, sub("_L", "_ratio", names(df[i])),  : provided 3 variables to replace 1 variables
```

The resulting values seem to be `A_L / A_R` for all cases, even for the IDs with `Side==1`. Could someone point out my mistake?
I know that there should be an easier `dplyr` approach as well, but I'm unfortunately not familiar with that yet.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` approach.

It relies on only mutating columns that end with `"L"`. Then using `cur_column()` to get the name of the column being worked on, we can create the name of the matching column with `str_replace` and `get()` its value.

We can combine this approach with `case_when` to consider the effect of `Side`.

Finally, we can use `rename_with` to fix up the column names since they will be based on the original `L` column name.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("L"), ~case_when(Side == 1 ~ get(str_replace(cur_column(),"L$","R"))/.,
                                           Side == 0 ~ ./get(str_replace(cur_column(),"L$","R"))),
                .names = "{.col}_Ratio")) %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(.,"_L",""),contains("_L_"))
  ID Side A_L A_R B_L B_R   A_Ratio   B_Ratio
1  1    0   7   5   6   3 1.4000000 2.0000000
2  2    1   3   2   3   1 0.6666667 0.3333333
3  3    0   6   3   4   5 2.0000000 0.8000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and also the explanation, this will help a lot to understand the workings of `dplyr`! I needed to get the library `stringr` before running, but then it worked out perfectly.

Comment: I have a follow up question if that's okay: I now want to use `dplyr::mutate` to binarize all of my ratios, turning all values of `A_ratio < 1` to `0` and all `A_ratio >= 1` to `1`. Do spot the mistake in the following `mutate(across(ends_with("ratio"), if_else (cur_column() < 1, 0, 1), .names = "{.col}_inf)`? Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that `cur_column()` returns a character string of the current column. If you want the values of that column, use `.`. Also, you need to preface anonymous function you have created with `~` which is interpreted by tidy evaluation as `function(x)` and assigns `x` to `.`, `.x`, and `..1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488532/ for more.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option

```
cols <- c("A", "B")
cbind(
    df,
    `colnames<-`(
        sapply(
            cols,
            function(x) {
                with(
                    df,
                    do.call("/", df[startsWith(names(df), x)])^(1 - 2 * Side)
                )
            }
        ), paste0(cols, "_ratio")
    )
)
```

gives

```
  ID Side A_L A_R B_L B_R   A_ratio   B_ratio
1  1    0   7   5   6   3 1.4000000 2.0000000
2  2    1   3   2   3   1 0.6666667 0.3333333
3  3    0   6   3   4   5 2.0000000 0.8000000
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer! My "real" dataframe now contains a lot more columns `A B C D ...`. Is there an easy way to upscale this approach to all of these columns, by either names or indices?