# Problem using lag() within a mutate() function (tidyverse)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add another column to a dataframe where the new column is a function of the previous value in the new column and a current row value.  I have tried to strip out irrelevant code and stick in easy numbers so that I might understand answers here. Given the following dataframe:

```
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

The next column (y) will add 5 to x and also add the previous row's value for y.  There's no previous value for y in the first row, so I define it as 0. So the first row value for y would be x+5+0 or 1+5+0 or 6. The second row would be x+5+y(from 1st row) or 2+5+6 or 13.  The dataframe should look like this:

```
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2 13
3 3 21
4 4 30
5 5 40
```

I tried this with case_when() and lag() functions like this:

```
test_df <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
test_df %>% mutate(y = case_when(x==1 ~ 6,
+                                    x>1 ~ x+5+lag(y)))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `y`.
> ℹ `y = case_when(x == 1 ~ 6, x > 1 ~ x + 5 + lag(y))`.
> x object 'y' not found
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I had thought y was defined when the first row was calculated.  Is there a better way to do this?   Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also use `purrr::accumulate` here:

```
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(y = accumulate(x+5, ~.x + .y))

  x  y
1 1  6
2 2 13
3 3 21
4 4 30
5 5 40
```

We can also use `accumulate` with regular base R synthax:

```
df %>% mutate(y = accumulate(x+5, function(x, y) {x + y}))
```

Comment: This is the path I tried to go down but don't fully understand the r documentation for accumulate.  Would you mind explaining the arguments to accumulate here, specifically the ~.x+.y?   (tilda and period)   Typically I have a function rather than just adding 5 to x.

Comment: NM....there is an explanation here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488162/use-of-tilde-and-period-in-r
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added an equilvalen version with basic R synthax,, so it may be clearer for begginers

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `lag` here at all. Just a `cumsum` should suffice.

```r
test_df %>% mutate(y = cumsum(x + 5))

#>   x  y
#> 1 1  6
#> 2 2 13
#> 3 3 21
#> 4 4 30
#> 5 5 40
```

---

**Data**

```r
test_df <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
```